# AWS cloudwatch dynamic labels not working properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I wrote a query to show some metrics in a graph in AWS cloudwatch. This query is grouping by 2 different dimensions, and the label by default is hard to understand:

[image]

I was trying to use dynamic queries to make the label more expressive:

`[action: ${PROP('Dim.Action')}, exception: ${PROP('Dim.exception')}]`

But the values of the dimentions never get printed (the name of the dimentions is correct):

[image]

I tried with other properties, such as namespace or metric name, but none of them get printed.

Any idea what might be preventing the dynamic queries from working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer on the AWS boards, this type of dynamic labelling is only supported for single metrics, not for queries, so this will just not work at the moment.

https://repost.aws/questions/QUOqinLRJFQIC_sI-NclckOw/aws-cloud-watch-graphed-metrics-are-dynamic-labels-with-dimensions-broken